# Jacobian of the inverse function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $F=${$y_i(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$}$_{i=1}^n$:$R^n\rightarrow $$R^n$ be a map with continous nonvanishing partial derivatives then its jacobian at a point $p$  is defined by the matrix $M_{i,j}(F)=\partial y_i/\partial x_j\lvert_p $. Now by the inverse function theorem $F$ has an inverse $F^{-1}=${$x_i(y_1,y_2,..,y_n)$} in a neigbourhood of $F(p)$ and so its jacobian must be defined by $M_{i,j}(F^{-1})=\partial x_i/\partial y_j\lvert_{F(p)} $. However from the univariate version of the inverse function theorem $\partial x_i/\partial y_j\lvert_{F(p)}=(\partial y_i/\partial x_j\lvert_{p})^{-1}$

**CONCLUSION:**

Therefore one can conclude that jacobian of the inverse function $F^{-1}$ at the point $F(p)$ is the same as the matrix of the jacobian of $F$ at $p$ but with its terms reciprocated.

By the multivariable case of inverse function theorem my conclusion is wrong infact it follows from the chain rule that $M_{i,j}(F^{-1})=M_{i,j}(F)^{-1}$.

Therefore my conclusion is wrong however I dont understand what is wrong behind my reasoning.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "with its terms reciprocated" Utterly false. The Jacobian matrix of $F^{-1}$ is the *inverse* of the Jacobian matrix of $F$.

Comment: Try a simple example such as $F:(x,y)\mapsto(x+y,y)$ to see how this fails.